# TSQL - decryptbypassphrase : Noise in strings

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, encryption, encoding

I'm using encryptbypassphrase/decyptbypassphrase to encrypt/decrypt data in my SqlServer 2008 R2 database.

It's working fine but the decryptbypassphrase is adding some "noise" to my data like the '\0'.
I managed that by a regex.

But now I got even worse situation, the function is returning "ýÿ:ýÿ ýÿOýÿuýÿiýÿ" instead of ": Oui" (I have to remove ýÿ from the string...)

I'm using the `CONTEXT_INFO` to store the passphrase, and retrieving it in my query.
The stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @PassPhrase VARCHAR(128)
EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetContextInfo]
@ContextInfo = @PassPhrase out
-- 
SELECT
ap.ActionPlanStatusId,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@PassPhrase,ap.Cost)) AS Cost,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@PassPhrase,ap.[Description])) AS [Description],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@PassPhrase, ap.Follow)) AS Follow,
ap.Id,
ap.ModifiedBy,
ap.ModifiedOn,
ap.RiskSheetId,
ap.TreatmentId
FROM dbo.ActionPlan ap
WHERE ap.Id = @ActionPlanId
```

Here is the code (I'm using a simple DataReader):

```
var actionPlan = new Core.ActionPlan
{
Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
ActionPlanStatusId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ActionPlanStatusId"]),
Cost = reader["Cost"] as string,
Description = reader["Description"] as string,
Follow = reader["Follow"] as string,
RiskSheetId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["RiskSheetId"]),
TreatmentId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TreatmentId"]),
ModifiedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ModifiedOn"])
};
```

Thanks

Comment: I've never used this function and have only glanced at the manpage for it. One thought occurs to me - the function seems very permissive about its arguments - `varchar` and `nvarchar` are both acceptable. Are you using the same type for both cleartext and passphrase? Just a thought.

Comment: Yes sir, I'm using varchar for both of them (tried nvarchar first but the decrypted text was "strange" like ㈱㐳㘵㠷).

Comment: OK, please can you post your code - maybe there's some problem with it and you're to close to it to see it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help any more, we'll need to wait until someone with experience using the function comes along. Have you investigated whther the problem is associated with the `CONVERT` operator? Maybe start by using SSMS and a simpler query that, say, just decrypts cost from the database, then work it up into a query that gets all the data, then wrap it into your C# code. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks @nurdglaw, that's exactly what I'm doing (going back to basics)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes sir, I'm using varchar for both of them (tried nvarchar first but the decrypted text was "strange" like ㈱㐳㘵㠷).

I believe those Japanese characters are the actual text, so I'd recommend going back to your NVARCHAR fix.  C# string datatype maps to Sql NVARCHAR datatype.

Comment: The actual text is in latin (French)

Answer (score 0):

`CONTEXT_INFO` is the probable culprit - it silently right-pads the data with zeros, so when you read it back, the data will differ from what you originally intended to store.

For example:

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x12;
PRINT CONTEXT_INFO();
```

Prints:

```
0x1200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The problem is that you'll get the same result with `SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x1200`. The zeros at the end become indistinguishable from the padding!

The only way to resolve this ambiguity that can I see, is to somehow encode the actual length of the data in the first byte of the `SET CONTEXT_INFO`, and then unpack the result of `CONTEXT_INFO()` accordingly.